# Problems trying to return records from SELECT statement using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am NEW to Postgresql. I downloaded v9.5 of Postgresql a couple of days ago and finding this DB pretty challenging in just trying to get my result set back from a pretty length SELECT statement.  I'm using the pgAdmin III product and hoping that I can see my result data but to no avail.

I've inherited this code and trying to make changes and trying NOT to HARD CODE the lines where the variables are being used if I can avoid it.

I've been googling about this for 2 days but again to no avail and I've tried many different variations but still not doing something right.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
********** Error **********
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Context: PL/pgSQL function getrecords() line 14 at SQL statement
```

Here is my code (sorry for the length of the query):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getRecords() RETURNS TABLE (
    title TEXT,


Number_of_visits BIGINT,
    Daily_Visit_Total_hours TEXT,
    First_Aid_Visits BIGINT,
    First_Aid_Total_hours TEXT,
    Major_Accident_Visits BIGINT,
    Major_Accident_Total_hours TEXT,
    Illness_Visits BIGINT,
    Illness_Total_hours TEXT,
    Medication_Administration_Visits BIGINT,
    Medication_Administration_Total_hours TEXT,
    Specialization_Visits BIGINT,
    Specialization_Total_hours TEXT,
    Diabetic_Visits BIGINT,
    Diabetic_Total_Hours TEXT) AS $$
#variable_conflict use_variable
DECLARE
    SYEAR_DATE NUMERIC;  
    START_DATE DATE;
    END_DATE DATE; 
    SCHOOL_ID NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    SYEAR_DATE := 2015;
    START_DATE := '2015-08-01';
    END_DATE := '2015-12-31';
    SCHOOL_ID := 002;

    SELECT DISTINCT
        '999 - DISTRICT TOTALS',
        dailyVisitTotal.count as Number_of_visits,
        round (dailyVisitTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Daily_Visit_Total_hours,
        firstAid.count as First_Aid_Visits,
        round (firstAid.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as First_Aid_Total_hours,
        majorAcc.count as Major_Accident_Visits,
        round (majorAcc.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Major_Accident_Total_hours,
        illness.count as Illness_Visits,
        round (illness.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Illness_Total_hours,
        medicationAdminTotal.count as Medication_Administration_Visits,
        round (medicationAdminTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Medication_Administration_Total_hours,
        specTotal.count as Specialization_Visits,
        round (specTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Specialization_Total_hours, 
        diabeticTotal.count as Diabetic_Visits,
        round (diabeticTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Diabetic_Total_Hours
    FROM student_enrollment se 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400000941
            legacy_field_id = 400000941
            and log_field2::date between START_DATE and END_DATE 
            --and log_field2::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) 
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) dailyVisitTotal 
    on (se.syear = dailyVisitTotal.syear)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400000941
            legacy_field_id=400000941
            and log_field2::date between START_DATE and END_DATE  
            --and log_field2::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) 
            and log_field4='Y'
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) firstAid 
    on (se.syear = firstAid.syear)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400000941
            legacy_field_id=400000941
            and log_field2::date between START_DATE and END_DATE 
            --and log_field2::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null)
            and log_field9='Y'
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) majorAcc 
    on (se.syear = majorAcc.syear)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400000941
            legacy_field_id=400000941
            and log_field2::date between START_DATE and END_DATE  
            --and log_field2::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) 
            and log_field5='Y'
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) illness 
    on (se.syear = illness.syear)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field2::numeric, 0)) as duration_total  
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400001237 
            legacy_field_id=400001237
            and log_field5::date between START_DATE and END_DATE
            --and log_field5::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field2 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field2 is null)
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) medicationAdminTotal 
    on (se.syear = medicationAdminTotal.syear) 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field11::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400009202 
            legacy_field_id=400009202
            and log_field3::date between START_DATE and END_DATE
            --and log_field3::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field11 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field11 is null)
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) specTotal 
    on (se.syear = specTotal.syear)  
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            se.syear, 
            count(*),
            sum(coalesce(log_field14::numeric, 0)) as duration_total 
        FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
        INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
            on (sle.source_id=se.student_id 
            and se.custom_9 is null 
            and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
            --and se.syear=2015
            and se.end_date is null)
        WHERE 
            --student_field_id = 400009003 
            legacy_field_id=400009003
            and log_field1::date between START_DATE and END_DATE
            --and log_field1::date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-12-31'
            and (log_field14 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field14 is null)
        GROUP BY se.syear
    ) diabeticTotal 
    on (se.syear = diabeticTotal.syear) 
    WHERE 
        se.syear = SYEAR_DATE
        --se.syear = 2015
        and se.end_date is null 
        and se.custom_9 is null 
        and se.syear=SYEAR_DATE 
        --and se.syear=2015
        and se.end_date is null
        and (
            specTotal.duration_total is not null 
            or dailyVisitTotal.duration_total is not null 
            or diabeticTotal.duration_total is not null 
            or medicationAdminTotal.duration_total is not null
        ) 
    ORDER BY 1;
END $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT * FROM getRecords();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `RETURN QUERY` before your query. That should tell postgres to return the records from your query.

```
BEGIN
    SYEAR_DATE := 2015;
    START_DATE := '2015-08-01';
    END_DATE := '2015-12-31';
    SCHOOL_ID := 002;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT DISTINCT

    '999 - DISTRICT TOTALS',
    dailyVisitTotal.count as Number_of_visits,
    round (dailyVisitTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Daily_Visit_Total_hours,
    firstAid.count as First_Aid_Visits,
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am now getting this error:
********** Error **********

ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
SQL state: 42804
Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type integer in column 1.
Context: PL/pgSQL function getrecords() line 14 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: `Daily_Visit_Total_hours DECIMAL` expects a `decimal` type but `round (dailyVisitTotal.duration_total / 60, 2) || 'hrs' as Daily_Visit_Total_hours` is converted to `text`. You should review return table declaration and query returned columns one by one and match them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do that now.  I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: I finally got my data types correct.  My apologies.  Now I have another question.  I should be seeing 139 rows in my TABLE.  But I'm only seeing 1 row with values summed up.  Should I be returning RECORD and NOT table if I want to see each individual ROW or RECORD?  Thanks.

Comment: The function returns whatever records the query returns. If your query returns a single record that's all you'll get. Try to execute the query directly, not inside a function, and see how many records it returns. Also you have hard coded values all over the query. Perhaps one of them is limiting your resultset to one record.

Comment: Thanks for your time cachique.  My apologies for all my confusion.  I was looking at the wrong SQL QUERY that showed multiple records vs the 1 record.  Sorry to have wasted your time on the last question.  I appreciate all your help in getting me through all the syntax issues.  PostgreSQL seems very cryptic as opposed to SQL Server which is what I normally work with.  Thank you again.